# Can Windows backup an entire drive?

Tags: windows, backup, disk-image, hard-drive-recovery, windows-backup

I want to make a full backup of the entire drive in Windows, without third party tools. I looked at the 'Backup Image' feature, but it requires me to select the partitions, and it does not list my Linux partitions, so I cannot include them.

So is there a way to make a full backup including all partitions (even the ones with unrecognized filesystems)?

Comment: Windows Backup cannot backup Linux partitions, what you describe, requires third-party software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 Backup no longer supports full-drive backups.
It used to do so in the past, but this feature was removed,
perhaps because it had too many gotchas (as some unlucky posters found out
on our site).

Unfortunately, full-disk backups are only possible now with third party tools.